# Accessing video from server on Android

Tags: android, video

We are trying to move some of our media files from our application to a server, but we can't seem to figure it out. I created a video, embedded it in my app, and it played fine. So I sent that same video file to someone to put on the server. I then went to my browser and typed in "http://www.server.com/Android-app/testVideo.mp4" and I get an error saying "Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device." I am using a Samsung Moment. So I was thinking it was something wrong with the server. But the video does work on someone's Droid, so that makes it sound like a phone compatibility issue. But it is the exact same file that worked on the phone earlier.

Is there a setting (on phone or server) that needs to be changed? I just can't make since of it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really given enough details to give a definitive answer, but the first thing I'd do would be to check the Content-Type in the response header.

Comment: I don't know anything about the server side of things, and I don't know what more details you want. My question is pretty general, what kind of special settings (if any) are required on either end? I'm not sure that it is specifically a server problem since it works on some devices. What do you mean by the Content-Type in the response header? I will provide as much information as I can if you can explain. Thanks.

Comment: @Brian: HTTP servers return a Content-Type header which indicates the "MIME type" of the response. eg: `text/html` for HTML, `audio/mp3` for MP3 files, etc. You probably want your server to be saying something like `video/mp4`. In Firefox try opening Live HTTP Headers (in the Tools menu) and the open your video. In Live HTTP Headers you'll see the request and also response headers. If the Content-Type in the response is something like `text/plain` or `application/octet-stream` you'll need to adjust your server settings. We'll need to know what server you're using if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does indicate video/mp4. Like I said, it does work on someone else's Android phone. What else could be the problem on my device?

Comment: Googling for "video is not valid for streaming to this device" turns up http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9044 . Comment #8 looks like it may be particularly helpful.

Comment: I actually came across that post earlier but I guess I overlooked that comment (or didn't understand on my first read). I downloaded handbrake and sent a video for them to put on the server, but it will probably be next week before I get to test it. If you would check back later in case I have a problem, I would appreciate it. I will post the results as soon as I can.

Comment: That solved the problem. The video simply wasn't made for what Android was calling "streaming"/progressive downloading. Converting with handbrake fixed the problem. Thanks for your help Laurence.

Comment: One more question, I am having a problem with the loading of this video. It just takes way too long. I opened another thread with the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109390/problem-converting-video-for-streaming-to-android-with-handbrake